# Best fundamental physics book

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

Good evening.

I'd like to know, in your opinion, what would be the best fundamental physics book for a freshman?

I want to start all over again.

Comment: [The Big Red Books, by R.P.F.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Feynman_Lectures_on_Physics)

Comment: I'd go to the source and read Newton's Principia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica  Better to read Newton's laws written by Newton himself rather than by others.